How to obtain confidence scores from transcriptions using faster_whisper?
I am using the faster_whisper Python library to transcribe audio files. Currently, I am able to get the transcriptions of audio data, but I'm unable to retrieve confidence scores for these transcriptions. The standard Whisper model and most implementations, including faster_whisper, don't seem to provide a confidence attribute directly in the segment object.
Here's a snippet of my code where I attempt to transcribe audio and would like to access confidence scores:
import numpy as np
import speech_recognition as sr
import faster_whisper

def main():
    os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'True' 

    audio_file_path = "audios/no_accent.wav"  
    model = "medium"  
    audio_model = faster_whisper.WhisperModel(model)

    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(audio_file_path) as source:
        audio = recognizer.record(source)  


    raw_data = audio.get_raw_data()
    if not raw_data:
        print("No data found in audio file.")
        return

    try:
        audio_np = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.int16).astype(np.float32) / 32768.0
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Error converting audio data to numpy array:", e)
        return

    segments, _ = audio_model.transcribe(audio_np, language="de")

    print("\nTranscription:")
    for segment in segments:
        print(f"Text: {segment.text}")  # Attempted to access segment.confidence here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I would like to know if there is a way to access or calculate confidence scores for each transcribed segment using faster_whisper or any modification required in the library to achieve this. Is there perhaps a lower-level access to the model outputs that would allow deriving such scores?

The problem with the approach you've mentioned is that the faster_whisper library does not provide confidence scores directly in the segment object.
The Whisper model and its implementations, including faster_whisper, do not have a built-in method to provide confidence scores for transcriptions.
